# java.sql.SQLException: SQL sentence is closed at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I am trying to insert a new row in my HSQLDB database. I have this code:

```
private final String SQL_CREAR_ATLETA=" INSERT INTO ATLETA (ID_ATLETA, DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, GENERO, NACIMIENTO, CORREO, TELEFONO, CODIGOFEDERACION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

@Override
public void crearAtleta(String dni, String nombre, String apellidos, char genero, Date nacimiento, String correo,
        String telefono, String codigoFederacion) throws SQLException {

    try {
        con = Jdbc.getConnection();
        pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL_CREAR_ATLETA);

        Integer idAtleta = calcularIdAtleta(); /*this is not null , it gives the next id , for example if there are 3 athlete in the DB , will return a 4*/

        pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(idAtleta)); // <- the code crash here
        pst.setString(2, nombre);
        pst.setString(3, apellidos);
        pst.setString(4, String.valueOf(genero));
        pst.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(nacimiento.getTime()));
        pst.setString(6, dni);
        pst.setString(7, correo);
        pst.setString(8, telefono);
        pst.setString(9, codigoFederacion);
        pst.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The program crashes at the line `pst.setString(1)` to set the id into the sql sentence. The stackTrace is this one :

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL sentence is closed
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatementBase.checkClosed(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.checkSetParameterIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
    at reestructurado.persistencia.impl.AtletasGatewayImpl.crearAtleta(AtletasGatewayImpl.java:50)
    at ui.UInscripcion$1.actionPerformed(UInscripcion.java:316)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: sentencia SQL está cerrada
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

I don't unserstand the problem. I tried to change the data type, but nothing seems to work. My table is this one:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace?

Comment: First, I think you should read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help. Second, you should include your table schema/data directly in your post, as text, not as a picture in an external site. Third, you need to explain what your actual error is and what you expected instead.

Comment: @Reimeus I think you are absolutely right! Roberto, please show us what does this method `calcularIdAtleta()` do!

Comment: But `String.valueOf(null)` should return `"null"` and according to the table definition  (`varchar(255)`) its a valid value...

Comment: sorry I still newbie here , i will edit the post in a few seconds

Comment: And not , if this case the id_atleta is the primary key of the table , so it cannot be null

Comment: I don't know why you are focussing on whether or not something is `null`.  The exception message >>says<< that the problem is that the statement has been closed.  I suspect that the connection is being closed inside your `calcularIdAtleta` method.

Comment: No the connexion is still working , the application still works after that.

Comment: Where do you declare your prepared statement `pst`? Please post all code that uses the statement. This is a good example why you want to _minimize the scope_ of your variables, i.e. declare them close to where they are used. Also, please post the code for `calcularIdAtleta`; if `pst` is re-assigned there, then that's your problem.

Comment: Check the value of `pst.isClosed()` immediately before and after the call to `calcularIdAtleta()`. That should tell you if the PreparedStatement is being closed as a side-effect of the `calcularIdAtleta()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you haven't disclosed all relevant code, the problem is likely that you are re-using the same `PreparedStatement` object across different methods. You are probably querying the next player id in `calcularIdAtleta()` using `pst`, which will leave the statement closed when `calcularIdAtleta()` returns. You shouldn't do that. Instead, use method-local variables; they make your code easier to read and less error-prone.

Try changing your method into this instead, essentially declaring the `PreparedStatement` locally:

```
public void crearAtleta(String dni, String nombre, 
        String apellidos, char genero, 
        Date nacimiento, String correo,
        String telefono, String codigoFederacion) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        ps = Jdbc.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_CREAR_ATLETA);

        Integer idAtleta = calcularIdAtleta();

        ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(idAtleta));
        ps.setString(2, nombre);
        ps.setString(3, apellidos);
        ps.setString(4, String.valueOf(genero));
        ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(nacimiento.getTime()));
        ps.setString(6, dni);
        ps.setString(7, correo);
        ps.setString(8, telefono);
        ps.setString(9, codigoFederacion);
        ps.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , that was the problem.